# Register a device specific autoplay handler

Tags: c#, windows, registry, windows-shell, autoplay

I am currently writing an app specific to the iPhone and I want to register my application in the Windows 7 AutoPlay popup for only the iPhone from what I understand from the Windows shell development page on the Microsoft learn site this can be done in the registry but I am failing to find an event handler or device handler for the iPhone  is this  something I will have write a COM handler for (hoping not) or do I need add the device in a different area of the registry

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you need to implement a COM object - for details see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301341.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: the second 2 links i have seen from my previous research but the first one i have not the article is based on windows xp though are the practices described in the article still done the same way in windows vista and windows 7 and going forward into windows 8 i have also experimented with the other 2 methods with the registry but as i mentioned before the iphone does not register as a device the current autoplay detects the iphone as a volume based device and searches it for media the same as plugging in an external hard drive i want to know if i can force registration of a device handler for

Comment: the iphone to run iphone related tasks handled by my application

Comment: currently it is designed for windows 7 but would like to make it compatible to xp and vista as well

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath then you will either need to stick to the XP way of things OR have different implementations for XP and Windows Vista/7... which way do you wanna go ?

Comment: if the xp way works in in the later way that would be fine but im also not against creating os specific implementations if it gives me better compatibility i was honestly hoping i could just stick a key in the registry with a device guid and have it register it as a device type then stick a key in the event handlers to create the autoplay option and assign it to the exe for my application but alas it doesnt look like this will be that simple

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath IIRC it is not that simple... didn't windows 7 so it might or might work with the XP method... though it should... give it a try